# ActiveRecord: chaining scopes and queries on associated records

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I came across a piece of ActiveRecord behavior that I find totally intuitive, but it took me by surprise. Given,

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :profile

  scope :active, -> { where(status: 1) }

  def self.find_by_code(code)
    Profile.find_by_code(code).person
  end
end

class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

I can combine the `active` scope and the `find_by_code` class method like,

```
User.active.find_by_code("ABC123")
```

and it will find the profile with the given code, then use the user_id on that profile to find the associated person. *AND* it remembers the `active` scope. How does it do that?

You can see in the generated queries that it first retrieves a `profile`, then queries for the relevant `person`:

```
SELECT `profiles`.* FROM `profiles` WHERE `profiles`.`code` = 'ABC123' LIMIT 1
SELECT `user`.* FROM `user` WHERE `user`.`active` = 1 AND `user`.`id` = 8 LIMIT 1
```

Unrelated, but I'm on Rails 3. I know the finder methods have changed a bit since then.

Comment: the scope is just syntactic sugar for the class method. As for how chaining combines queries, that's a more complicated topic, see  [activerecord query interface](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html) which is built on [arel](https://github.com/rails/arel)

Comment: And class methods (include those that come from `scope`) are patched into the relations that `User.where(...)` returns. BTW, the structure of your `find_by_code` means that `Person.active.find_by_code("ABC123")` and `User.find_by_code("ABC123")` do the same thing as `find_by_code` doesn't pay any attention to its `self`.

Comment: @muistooshort That's exactly what I thought too, but it's not the case. Given the code associated with an active user, it finds the user; given the code associated with an inactive user, it returns nil.

Comment: Just realized I had mistyped `Person` when I meant `User` in the example. Maybe that created confusion.

Comment: Maybe you should update your question to include real code that you've really used.